# How can I check whether a player is looking at an object? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have orbs that you can teleport to when you click e and when you are looking at the orb, Basically I want to check whether the player is looking at an orb.

Comment: Shoot a [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and determine if it intersects with the objects you are looking for. You can also restrict the layer you are casting for to only interactable objects.

Comment: Define "looking at" more clearly ... Raycast is good if you want to check an exact direction .. or is it enough that the object is within a certain range?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Physics.Raycast`. This casts a ray (infinite line) from point a, in direction of a certain Vector3. You should use this code:

```
//set mask to the mask of the object you
//want to look at in the editor.
public LayerMask mask; 

private void Update()
{
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out var hit, Mathf.Infinity, mask))
    {
        var obj = hit.collider.gameObject;
    
        Debug.Log($"looking at {obj.name}", this);
    }
}
```

Here are some extra resources:

- [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)
- [`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html)

Comment: So would I add this to the player?

Comment: Attach it to the camera, or whatever you want to be casting a line from (if you have a standard game, attach it to the camera.) Just add it to the update function and everything should work. If it doesn’t tell me what happens.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LookingAtOrb.Update () (at Assets/LookingAtOrb.cs:21)

Is what happens when I attach it to the camera

Comment: I changed it. Tell me if you get another error.

Comment: Assets\LookingAtOrb.cs(27,2): error CS1513: } expected

it has a closing collumn however

Comment: You need to make sure that the if statements and the class is starting and ending in {}.

Comment: Yep I made sure they do still get the error for some reason

Comment: Edit original answer to show current code (including using UnityEngine and the class too) and I will be gone for the next hour or less, so try and look up these errors on google, and I will help when I get back

Comment: @ken you have a `)` too much after `out hit` .. you don't want to close the `Raycast` at this point but after `mask` .. and then you have to add one additional `)` to close the `if` as well

Comment: I think you fixed it, should I do anything?

Comment: Note that this will absolutely kill performance if used in game loops like `Update` and `FixedUpdate`